# Python non-greedy regex to clean xml

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy, non-greedy

I have an 'xml file' file that has some unwanted characters in it

```
<data>
  <tag>blar </tag><tagTwo> bo </tagTwo>
  some extra 
  characters not enclosed that I want to remove
  <anothertag>bbb</anothertag>
</data>
```

I thought the following non-greedy substitution would remove the characters that were not properly encased in `<sometag></sometag>`

```
re.sub("</([a-zA-Z]+)>.*?<","</\\1><",text)
            ^          ^ ^     ^      text is the xml txt.  
         remember tag, | |     put tag back without and reopen next tag
               read everything until the next '<' (non-gready)
```

This regex seems only to find the position indicated with the `[[]]` in `</tag>[[]]<tagTwo>`
What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
The motivation for this question has been solved (see comments, I had a stray & in the xml file which was causing it not to parse - it had nothing to do with the characters that I want to delete).  However, I am still curious as to whether the regex is possible (and what was wrong with my attempt) and so I don't delete the question.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: I'm not trying to parse xml.  I'm trying to clean the xml file so that I can have it accepted by the parser.  Any non-regex suggestions as to how to do this are welcome

Comment: Which parser doesn't accept that?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams `xml.dom.mindom` I have edited question to include backtrace

Comment: Sounds like you have a stray ampersand in there.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Bah! Looks like I do.  (how did you know that?)

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, okay when I run a substitution to replace "&" with "and" my problem goes away.  However, I would rather keep the text as it was written, how do I keep the & and still have it pass (I tried substuting "\&" but that didn't succeed.

Comment: The character entity reference for an ampersand is `&amp;`. You can't just do a global S+R though, as that could mess up other valid things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dot does not match newlines unless you specify the `re.DOTALL` flag.

```
re.sub("</([a-zA-Z]+)>.*?<","</\\1><",text, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

should work fine. (If it does not, my python is at fault, not the regex. Please correct.)

I think it is good practise to be as precise as possible when defining character classes that are to be repeated. This helps to prevent [catastrophic backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html). Therefore, I'd use `[^<]*` instead of `.*?` with the added bonus that it now finds stray characters after the last tag. This would not need the `re.DOTALL` flag any longer, since `[^<]` does match newlines.

Answer (score 1):

```
 "</[^>]+?>[^<>]+?<"
```

in ipython:

```
In [1]: a="<data>  <tag>blar </tag><tagTwo> bo </tagTwo>  some extra   characters not enclosed that I want to remove  <anothertag>bbb</anothertag></data>"

In [2]: import re

In [3]: re.sub( "(</[^>]+?>)[^<>]+?<" ,"\\1<",a)
Out[3]: '<data>  <tag>blar </tag><tagTwo> bo </tagTwo><anothertag>bbb</anothertag></data>'
```