# How can I remove junk from outside valid XML tags?

Tags: python, xml, perl, sed, awk

I have a series of XML files produced from a data playback utility.  The utility produces correctly formed XML tags.  Unfortunately, the utility isn't perfect.  Some of the Java objects it attempts to serialize fail and they are simply inserted (as binary blobs) in between these other, valid XML tags.

For example...

```
<track>
<cto>Valid_XML_HERE</cto>@Binary_Blob_of_Junk@<cto>(...)</cto>
</track>
```

Environment is RHEL-5, which means Python 2.4, Perl, or SED/AWK solutions are usable.

Any suggestions on how to remove the junk?

Comment: You can use regex (in particular, `re.sub` from `re` in the python library). Answer can be found at similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7671112/python-non-greedy-regex-to-clean-xml

Comment: Depends on what exactly the "junk" looks like.

Comment: The "junk" is just that, binary data.  There is no obvious pattern, other than something to the effect of "java.Object" appearing in the middle.  I'm currently pursuing a solution using Python's 're' module, as suggested, but so far have only been successful in isolating the individual <cto></cto> tags, which solves the first problem of trimming binary junk from the top/bottom of the file.  I'm now trying to get the junk removed from between valid tags within these <cto> tags.  The problem is some tags are single lines and don't have a </tag> component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I built off of Birei's suggestion to inspect tree elements, but came up with a SED-only solution.  As shown in the OP, the `<cto>` tags happen to be on one continuous line.  The solution, then, was to split the lines such that each `<cto>` tag was on a new line -- thus, also isolating the junk binary data on new lines -- and then simply select lines starting with a `<cto>` tag.

The `<tracks>` and `</tracks>` tag can simply be added to the new file via CAT.

Here are the SED commands that I've tested and confirm to work...

Step 1.  Isolate the `<cto>` tags to be on new lines.

```
sed -i "s/<cto/\n<cto/g;s/<\/cto>/<\/cto>\n/g" ${FILE}
```

Step 2. Select only the lines starting with a `<cto>` tag.

```
sed -i "/<cto/p" ${FILE}
```

Step 3. Format the new XML document.

```
xmllint --format "${FILE}" > foo.xml
```

Thanks for all of your respective inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Other way to remove the text of `track` tags using the `XML::Twig` parser:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
    twig_handlers => {
        track => sub {
            for my $t ( $_->children() ) { 
                if ( $t->is_text ) { 
                    $t->set_text( '' );
                }   
            }   
        }   
    },  
    pretty_print => 'indented',
)->parsefile( shift)->print;
```

Run it with your file as first (and unique) argument:

```
perl script.pl xmlfile
```

Comment: I think the requirement is to remove all text children of a `track` element. This just wipes the track and all its information.

Comment: @Borodin: You are right. Thank you. I will try to fix it in a while.

Comment: It turns out that I don't have access to XML::Twig on this workstation, which is equipped with a bare minimum install of perl-5.8.8 (circa 2006).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick Perl solution for you.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -Tw

use strict;
use warnings;
use English qw( -no_match_vars $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR );

my $text = do { local $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR = undef; <>; };

my @ctos = $text =~ m{<cto>( .+? )</cto>}xmsg;

if ( @ctos ) {

    printf '<track><cto>%s</cto></track>', join '</cto><cto>', @ctos;
}

print "\n";
```

You can pipe your track text through it like so:

```
$:  cat track.txt | ./clean_track.pl 
<track><cto>Valid_XML_HERE</cto><cto>(...)</cto></track>
```

Comment: Thanks, ddoxey.  This looks promising.  I'll try this out in the lab tomorrow and let you know how it goes.